# How to test elements in a collection in a test class?

Tags: java, junit

I want to test collection elements in test class,which meathod can get collection elements.

I use the getcollection.get() to get elements, and I cast the collection to an ArrayList type in the get method, but it seems to have no effect.

```
public Recipe(String name, String description, double price, Ingredient... ingredients) {

       if(ingredients==null ) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("ingredients can't be null or an empty string");   
       }
       custmerOrderIngredients=new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
        for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients) {
            custmerOrderIngredients.add(ingredient);
        }

 }

public Collection<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
  return (ArrayList<Ingredient>)custmerOrderIngredients;//here i case the collection to an ArrayList type.//
 }

@Test
    public void testGetIngredients() throws Exception {
        Ingredient in1=new Ingredient("burger");
        Ingredient in2=new Ingredient("chicken");
        Recipe r1=new Recipe("Beef burger", "burger with beef", 5.00,in1,in2);
        assertEquals("burger",  r1.getIngredients().get(0).getName());  
    }

/**
 *Ingredient
*/

    public Ingredient(String name) throws Exception {

    if(name==null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name parameter is null.");

        name = name.trim().toLowerCase();
        name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+name.substring(1);   

        this.name=name;

    }
```

I expect the assertEquals can success test collection have "burger" elements.

Comment: AssertJ has some very nice methods for this, I personally use it in every project: http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/

Comment: Can you show the code of your `Ingredient` class?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `r1.getIngredients().get(0)` will not compile?

Comment: could not use get() to gain the collection element, I think, and I post my Ingredient constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Ingredient` class constructor:

```
name = name.trim().toLowerCase();
name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+name.substring(1);
```

You perform some calculations on the `name` object. And the final result of it is "Burger".

"Burger" does not equal "burger". That's why your assert method does not work.

If you want to compare the names case-insensitive, you can do it like this:

```
assertThat("burger", IsEqualIgnoringCase.equalToIgnoringCase(r1.getIngredients().get(0).getName()));
```

or simply convert the actual one to lower-case:

```
assertEquals("burger", r1.getIngredients().get(0).getName().toLowerCase());
```